# Single htaccess redirect for all subdomains (www and non-www) to folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site which has 40 subdomains.

I want to add 301 htaccess redirect for....

1) domain.com to www.domain.com

2) www.sub-domain.domain.com to www.domain.com/sub-domain

3) sub-domain.domain.com to www.domain.com/sub-domain

I have achieved 1 and 3 redirects with below code....

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub-domain\.domain\.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I do not understand why you vote down. Because for me it's a good question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www).+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^%1 http://www.domain.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: how to contact you? i have another issue which i want to post and notify you.

Comment: as i said your solution worked like a charm. the site i am working on has all the pages (more than 3000) in html. i have converted them into php.

how to set 301 redirect from .html to php without disturbing previous redirect setting. Please note that there are also google-webmaster-tool verification html file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best solution for me is to continue using .html for your .php pages. You can add new rules before the latter. Add a new question if you can not find how to do.

Comment: added this line RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1.php this solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code will help you with the first option, and it works regardless the domain, it is generic so you dont have to create 40 lines of code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```